# PHP loop integer join onto resource array

Tags: php, arrays

I am querying the database which outputs as resource
eg

```
$tracker=get_record("tracker_entries", "userid", $user, "course", $course->id, "unitid" , $unit);
```

OUTPUTS AS:

```
$tracker->obj;
```

I have wrote a loop which works fine. The bit I am struggling with is adding the $f integer to the resource. ie joining the 2 variables.

```
$tracker->obj.$f;
```

It sees them as 2 sepearte echos, does anybody know how I can join the variables so it outputs

```
$tracker->obj1
$tracker->obj2
$tracker->obj3
$tracker->obj4
```

etc

Hope this makes sense, here is my code

```
 $f=0;
 for($number=1;$number<6;$number+=1){
 for($i=0;$i<6;$i+=1){
 $f+=1;  
 $theunit = $unitx->pc.$f;
 $thetracker = $tracker->obj.$f;
 $feedback = $tracker->feedback.$f;
       if(!empty($theunit)){
          echo'<tr>
              <td class="pc" valign="top" valign="top" align="left" width="5%"><strong>'.$number.'.'.$i.'</strong> </td>
              <td valign="top" class="pc" align="left">'.$theunit.'</td>
              <td valign="top" class="pc" align="left">'.$feedback.'</td>
              <td valign="top" class="pc" align="center">'.$thetracker.'</td>
          </tr>';
      }
 }
 }
```

var_dump of $tracker (bit large)

object(stdClass)#491 (208) { ["id"]=> string(5) "11810" ["course"]=> string(3) "958" ["unitid"]=> string(4) "1089" ["userid"]=> string(4) "9659" ["obj1"]=> string(2) "No" ["obj2"]=> string(3) "Yes" ["obj3"]=> string(0) "" ["obj4"]=> string(0) "" ["obj5"]=> string(0) "" ["obj6"]=> string(0) "" ["obj7"]=> string(0) "" ["obj8"]=> string(0) "" ["obj9"]=> string(0) "" ["obj10"]=> string(0) "" ["obj11"]=> string(0) "" ["obj12"]=> string(0) "" ["obj13"]=> string(0) "" ["obj14"]=> string(0) "" ["obj15"]=> string(0) "" ["obj16"]=> string(0) "" ["obj17"]=> string(0) "" ["obj18"]=> string(0) "" ["obj19"]=> string(0) "" ["obj20"]=> string(0) "" ["obj21"]=> string(0) "" ["obj22"]=> string(0) "" ["obj23"]=> string(0) "" ["obj24"]=> string(0) "" ["obj25"]=> string(0) "" ["obj26"]=> string(0) "" ["obj27"]=> string(0) "" ["obj28"]=> string(0) "" ["obj29"]=> string(0) "" ["obj30"]=> string(0) "" ["obj31"]=> string(0) "" ["obj32"]=> string(0) "" ["obj33"]=> string(0) "" ["obj34"]=> string(0) "" ["obj35"]=> string(0) "" ["obj36"]=> string(0) "" ["obj37"]=> string(0) "" ["obj38"]=> string(0) "" ["obj39"]=> string(0) "" ["obj40"]=> string(0) "" ["obj41"]=> string(0) "" ["obj42"]=> string(0) "" ["obj43"]=> string(0) "" ["obj44"]=> string(0) "" ["obj45"]=> string(0) "" ["obj46"]=> string(0) "" ["obj47"]=> string(0) "" ["obj48"]=> string(0) "" ["obj49"]=> string(0) "" ["obj50"]=> string(0) "" ["obj51"]=> string(0) "" ["obj52"]=> string(0) "" ["obj53"]=> string(0) "" ["obj54"]=> string(0) "" ["obj55"]=> string(0) "" ["obj56"]=> string(0) "" ["obj57"]=> string(0) "" ["obj58"]=> string(0) "" ["obj59"]=> string(0) "" ["obj60"]=> string(0) "" ["obj61"]=> string(0) "" ["obj62"]=> string(0) "" ["obj63"]=> string(0) "" ["obj64"]=> string(0) "" ["obj65"]=> string(0) "" ["obj66"]=> string(0) "" ["obj67"]=> string(0) "" ["obj68"]=> string(0) "" ["obj69"]=> string(0) "" ["obj70"]=> string(0) "" ["obj71"]=> string(0) "" ["obj72"]=> string(0) "" ["obj73"]=> string(0) "" ["obj74"]=> string(0) "" ["obj75"]=> string(0) "" ["obj76"]=> string(0) "" ["obj77"]=> string(0) "" ["obj78"]=> string(0) "" ["obj79"]=> string(0) "" ["obj80"]=> string(0) "" ["obj81"]=> string(0) "" ["obj82"]=> string(0) "" ["obj83"]=> string(0) "" ["obj84"]=> string(0) "" ["obj85"]=> string(0) "" ["obj86"]=> string(0) "" ["obj87"]=> string(0) "" ["obj88"]=> string(0) "" ["obj89"]=> string(0) "" ["obj90"]=> string(0) "" ["obj91"]=> string(0) "" ["obj92"]=> string(0) "" ["obj93"]=> string(0) "" ["obj94"]=> string(0) "" ["obj95"]=> string(0) "" ["obj96"]=> string(0) "" ["obj97"]=> string(0) "" ["obj98"]=> string(0) "" ["obj99"]=> string(0) "" ["obj100"]=> string(0) "" ["obj101"]=> string(0) "" ["obj102"]=> string(0) "" ["obj103"]=> string(0) "" ["obj104"]=> string(0) "" ["obj105"]=> string(0) "" ["obj106"]=> string(0) "" ["obj107"]=> string(0) "" ["obj108"]=> string(0) "" ["obj109"]=> string(0) "" ["obj110"]=> string(0) "" ["obj111"]=> string(0) "" ["obj112"]=> string(0) "" ["obj113"]=> string(0) "" ["obj114"]=> string(0) "" ["obj115"]=> string(0) "" ["obj116"]=> string(0) "" ["obj117"]=> string(0) "" ["obj118"]=> string(0) "" ["obj119"]=> string(0) "" ["obj120"]=> string(0) "" ["obj121"]=> string(0) "" ["obj122"]=> string(0) "" ["obj123"]=> string(0) "" ["obj124"]=> string(0) "" ["obj125"]=> string(0) "" ["obj126"]=> string(0) "" ["obj127"]=> string(0) "" ["obj128"]=> string(0) "" ["obj129"]=> string(0) "" ["obj130"]=> string(0) "" ["obj131"]=> string(0) "" ["obj132"]=> string(0) "" ["obj133"]=> string(0) "" ["obj134"]=> string(0) "" ["obj135"]=> string(0) "" ["obj136"]=> string(0) "" ["obj137"]=> string(0) "" ["obj138"]=> string(0) "" ["obj139"]=> string(0) "" ["obj140"]=> string(0) "" ["obj141"]=> string(0) "" ["obj142"]=> string(0) "" ["obj143"]=> string(0) "" ["obj144"]=> string(0) "" ["obj145"]=> string(0) "" ["obj146"]=> string(0) "" ["obj147"]=> string(0) "" ["obj148"]=> string(0) "" ["obj149"]=> string(0) "" ["obj150"]=> string(0) "" ["obj151"]=> string(0) "" ["obj152"]=> string(0) "" ["obj153"]=> string(0) "" ["obj154"]=> string(0) "" ["obj155"]=> string(0) "" ["obj156"]=> string(0) "" ["obj157"]=> string(0) "" ["obj158"]=> string(0) "" ["obj159"]=> string(0) "" ["obj160"]=> string(0) "" ["obj161"]=> string(0) "" ["obj162"]=> string(0) "" ["obj163"]=> string(0) "" ["obj164"]=> string(0) "" ["obj165"]=> string(0) "" ["obj166"]=> string(0) "" ["obj167"]=> string(0) "" ["obj168"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback1"]=> string(10) "fghj " ["feedback2"]=> string(10) "gfhj " ["feedback3"]=> string(10) "fghj " ["feedback4"]=> string(10) "fghj " ["feedback5"]=> string(10) "fghj " ["feedback6"]=> string(10) "ghhj " ["feedback7"]=> string(7) "ghj " ["feedback8"]=> string(8) "fgjh " ["feedback9"]=> string(8) "fghj " ["feedback10"]=> string(8) "fgjh " ["feedback11"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback12"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback13"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback14"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback15"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback16"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback17"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback18"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback19"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback20"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback21"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback22"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback23"]=> string(8) "fghj " ["feedback24"]=> string(7) "ghj " ["feedback25"]=> string(8) "fgjh " ["feedback26"]=> string(8) "fghj " ["feedback27"]=> string(8) "fgjh " ["comment"]=> string(0) "" ["iv"]=> string(0) "" ["grade"]=> string(0) "" ["ivgrade"]=> string(0) "" ["ivdate"]=> string(0) "" ["assessorgrade"]=> string(0) "" ["gradedate"]=> string(0) "" ["assessordate"]=> string(0) "" ["partofiv"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: Did you mean "concatenating" by "join"?

Comment: ah ha!!! ${$unitx->pc.$f}; would this be the way???

Answer (score 0):

Use **scalar**

Sample code:

```
<?php
$obj = (object) 'ciao';
$obj->test1 = (object) 'test1';

$i = 1;

echo $obj->test1->scalar . PHP_EOL;

echo $obj->{'test'.$i}->scalar . PHP_EOL;
```

Your code:

```
$theunit = $unitx->{'pc'.$f}->scalar;
$thetracker = $tracker->{'obj'.$f}->scalar;
$feedback = $tracker->{'feedback'.$f}->scalar;
```

Comment: I have added the var_dump in my question

Comment: Sorry dont get what this does, and it does not work. do I need the top part of the sample code?

Comment: only change your code with the code I added bellow "Your code"
to assign the value to $theunit for use: $theunit = $unitx->{'pc'.$f}->scalar;
And so for the 3 variables.